# Apache Error on Mac OS X Lion

Tags: macos, apache2

I keep getting this error on my apache install. I have php module enabled on it. Rest is the standard installation

```
[Thu Dec 08 06:46:42 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: /usr/htdocs
[Thu Dec 08 06:46:42 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: /usr/htdocs
```

Any ideas why does this happen and how to fix it.

Thanks

Comment: Look for `/usr/htdocs` in your configuration file -- include the surrounding bits, too..

Comment: there is no mention of htdocs file in httpd.conf file. only that the ServerRoot is set "/usr"

Comment: look in the virtual host conf files

Comment: no mention of htdocs anywhere in /etc/apache2 directory

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Some problem with Mac OS X Web preferences. I had to go and enable Web Sharing from preferences to make it work,

System Preferences->Sharing->Web Sharing and restart Apache

I think its got something to do with apache user not having permission to access my DocumentRoot, which is not entirely obvious from the error_log.

Comment: I got the same problem. Unfortunately this solution doesn't work for me

Comment: @Flov - You might have errors or omissions in your `httpd.conf` file. Can you confirm apache is running and you've included the appropriate doc root etc?

Comment: I know apache very well, but was new to this wrinkle in OSX 10.7. THANK YOU for the easy fix. :)

Answer (score 11):

This error is caused by not having the proper `httpd.conf` settings.

The reason the error goes away if you turn web sharing on is that the appropriate configs are only loaded if web sharing is on due to some `IfDefine` tags that look like:

```
<IfDefine WEBSHARING_ON>
    ...
</IfDefine>
```

Thus, virtual hosts, and Library/WebServer/Documents as root etc only get activate if websharing is on.

For Lion a solution is to turn web sharing on.

For Mount Lion there is no web sharing, so that is not an option, and **you have to remove
the IfDefine tags, while keeping the content that is between them**.

After changing your httpd.conf file you should always run:

```
apachectl configtest
```

This will let you know if you have syntax errors, module errors, etc.

Comment: I can't thank you enough :) I didn't know about the `apachectl configtest`!